# Does Cordova support certificate pinning on iOS?

Tags: cordova

Does Cordova support certificate pinning on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova doesn't support certificate pinning but can be achieved using the [Intel App Security API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/app-security-api/api) which comes as a [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/AppSecurityApi/com-intel-security-cordova-plugin).

**Secure Transport send with pinned public key snippet:**

```
// TODO change server PK
var publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
    "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2swYYzD99BcjGlZ+W988\n" +
    "bDjkcbd4kdS8odhM+KhDtgPpTSEHCIjaWC9mOSm9BXiLnTjoBbdqfnGk5sRgprDv\n" +
    "gOSJKA+eJdbtg/OtppHHmMlCGDUUna2YRpIuT8rxh0PBFpVXLVDviS2Aelet8u5f\n" +
    "a9IAjbkU+BQVNdnARqN7csiRv8lVK83Qlz6cJmTM386DGXHKTubU1XupGc1V3sjs\n" +
    "0l44U+VcT4wt/lAjNvxm5suOpDkZALeVAjmRCw7+OC7RHQWa9k0+bw8HHa8sHo9g\n" +
    "OeL6NlMTOdReJivbPagUvTLrGAMoUgRx5aszPeE4uwc2hGKceeoWMPRfwCvocWvk\n" +
    "+QIDAQAB\n" +
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

// create the Transport Secure instance
intel.security.secureTransport.open( {url: "https://software.intel.com/en-us/app-security-api/api", serverKey: publicKey} )

// send the request
.then (function (transportInstanceID) {
        // send the HTTPS request
        return intel.security.secureTransport.sendRequest( {instanceID: transportInstanceID, requestBody: "data to send"} );
})

// process the response
.then (function(response) {
    // assign response HTTP status
    var responseHttpStatus = response.responseHttpStatus;

    // assign response body
    var responseBody = response.responseBody;

    // assign response header
    var responseHeader = response.responseHeader;

    // now we have the following items:
    // the response status in 'responseHttpStatus'
    // the response body in 'responseBody'
    // the response header in 'responseHeader'

    // we can use those in our code.
    doSomethingAfterReceiveWithKeyPinning(response);
})

.catch (function(error) {
    console.log("Fail, error code is: " + error.code + ", error message is: " + error.message);
});
```

Source of the snippet is from the original documentation: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/604523

Answer (score 1):

Cordova doesn't, but like most functionality, it is possible to do using a plugin.

"Cordova / Phonegap plugin for communicating with HTTP servers. Allows for SSL pinning!" -- https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP

Like it says in he [Cordova Security Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/security/index.html#certificate-pinning), "...assuming your app is able to do all of its network requests using the plugin (i.e.: no traditional XHR/AJAX requests, etc)."